# CSS not being applied in Visual Studio 2012 designer?

Tags: css, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, designer

I have some css, which when inside my CSS file isn't applied to my designer in Visual Studio, but is applied to the page when I publish it.  This issue is slowing down site development massively as I'm trying to pick up CSS as I go...

Here's a sample bit of CSS:

```
.header {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
    color: #222;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
        text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #fff;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
                                       from(#ccc), to(#999));
}
```

Me applying the CSS on the page:

```
<header>
    <asp:Label ID="lblQuestion" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="16pt" Text="Your question goes here..." CssClass="header"></asp:Label>
</header>
```

Me adding the CSS to the page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css" media="only screen and (max-width: 480px)" />
```

I'm pretty new to CSS, so I'm hoping someone can tell me what I'm doing that is stopping Visual Studio rendering the CSS properly in the designer...

Also, if I put my CSS tags directly in the page then it works, but I'd much rather keep my CSS out in it's own file, where it can be reused.

Example style working:

```
<style>
    .header {
        background-color: #ccc;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
        color: #222;
        display: block;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #fff;
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ccc), to(#999));
    }
</style>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest taking a look at Jeff Widmer's blog post, [Why does Visual Studio not resolve my CSS class names?](http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids/archive/2009/06/07/why-does-visual-studio-not-resolve-my-css-class-names.aspx)

Basically, site relative path's aren't supported by Visual Studio. It is the same reason why intellisense doesn't work for javascript.

He offers a fix for this issue:

```
<link href="/content/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <% if (false) {%>
        <link href="../../content/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <% } %>
```

UPDATE:

The problem here was the media element in the link tag for the css. It doesn't appear that VS knows what that tag is and thus doesn't try to resolve the url.

In this case, the css file is in the same folder as the page, so it would work. But, if the css file is moved into another folder, then it would stop working and the fix above would solve the issue.

Comment: I actually had to remove the "media="only screen and (max-width: 480px)"" part of my link to the stylesheet.  If you update your answer to explain that, that bit of text checks the screen size and enables a stylesheet based on that, then I can mark you as the answer :)

Comment: @Vijay ~ That is a completely different question.

Comment: That's not a question.  That's me telling you what fixed my issue (the answer) and saying if you are willing to explain the issue so that other people can find it I'll give you the points.  If not that's fine, I can make an answer and mark it as the answer, just thought I'd be nice... Visual Studio 2012 DOES resolve my class names, and site relative paths do work in the designer in 2012 (not sure about <2012), my IDE works fine.  It was just that "Media" part which was the issue.  Your call, I'll be back tomorrow, if  there's no edit from you I'll make an answer :)

Comment: @Vijay ~ I'm going to guess that VS doesn't know about the media element. Thus, it doesn't try to resolve the path. The reason it works for you without that, is b/c the css file is located right in the same folder as your page. Normally you'd put it in it's own CSS or Media folder.

Comment: @Vijay ~ Try defining the media in the CSS instead: http://unmatchedstyle.com/news/working-with-media-queries-and-min-width.php

Comment: Add this stuff to your answer and I'll accept!  I just want it to be clear to other who come across this how it was fixed (remove media tag).  The other stuff is interesting and useful for me (and others), but as it stands it didn't fix the issue.  IF you want the points add some extra stuff (including media tag info) to your answer, otherwise I'll add my own answer later.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer :D