# Visual Studio 2012 w/ PHP Tools -- Debugging Issue/locating referenced (CSS/JQuery) files

Tags: php, jquery, css, visual-studio-2012, reference

I'm currently working on a project using the PHP Tools add-on for Visual Studio 2012.

Currently, I am attempting to debug a page that attempts to link to a CSS file. There is currently no PHP scripting on the page because I am attempting to set up the basic template and build from there.

Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

When I debug this page, the HTML displays, but without any formatting or images. If I paste the CSS directly into the file the formatting will work. I also am attempting to reference several jquery files what suffer from this same problem.

When attempting to debug a php page that say... Generates an HTML form, validates data, and then passes info into my Database I have no issues.

If I make an html file containing identical code and simply right click Open with> Google Chrome, everything functions/displays as intended.

I have made sure that all files/folders are within the same directory as the file being debugged.

Could anyone diagnose this issue? I need everything to be in working order within my VS2012 Project Environment.

TL;DR -- PHP Project with Visual Studio 2012 extension. On debug, pages won't properly access images, css, or script files referenced locally. Help.

Comment: on the generated HTML, did you check the path of the CSS .? if the CSS is not loaded, its because the file could not be loaded, so it should be a path issue

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788854/css-not-being-applied-in-visual-studio-2012-designer

Comment: That's where I believe my problem lies. The path I've specified in my code leads to (what I believe to be) the location of the file, but it won't load.

I've tried several different paths, but nothing has worked so far. I feel as if Visual Studio is rooting from a different spot than I believe it to be.. but I don't know how to identify the right path (If that's the problem).

Comment: @JamieSchembri Unfortunately that solution did not work for me. I read both the solution provided there as well as the original blog.