# Why does not CSS appy to the HTML in Visual Studio?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, hyperlink

I am working on a very simple ASP.NET project in Visual Studio 2013. I added an HTML, a CSS and JS file(each empty). I created the links in between the pages, and I put them into the same folder.

```
<head>
<title>Analog Clock</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
```

I figured out, that I didn't mispelt anything, but my CSS doesn't apply on the HTML Ids.
My HTML body:

```
<svg width="140" height="140">
<circle id="clock-face" cx="70" cy="70" r="65" />
<line id="h-hand" x1="70" y1="70" x2="70" y2="38" />
<line id="m-hand" x1="70" y1="70" x2="70" y2="20" />
<line id="s-hand" x1="70" y1="70" x2="70" y2="12" />
<line id="s-tail" x1="70" y1="70" x2="70" y2="56" />
<text x="62" y="18">12</text>
<text x="126" y="76">3</text>
<text x="66" y="130">6</text>
<text x="7" y="76">9</text>
</svg>
```

And my CSS (stlye.css):

```
 #clock-face{
      stroke:black;
      stroke-width:2px;
      fill:white;
 }
```

I looked up stackoverflow and I found this link:
[CSS not being applied in Visual Studio 2012 designer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788854/css-not-being-applied-in-visual-studio-2012-designer)

It says to change the link to this.(Obviously I put my folders name instead of content)

```
<link href="/content/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<% if (false) {%>
    <link href="../../content/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<% } %>
```

So did I, but I got the same result. Apologies for the dumb question, but I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: If you let Visual Studio intellisense the path, does it work?

Comment: Drag and drop the file from the solution explorer to the screen that will create a default path for you to assure it's correct

Comment: Yes, it is ok, now should I do the same to the js file?